# Unwanted spacing between image and a div

Tags: html, css, spacing

I have some css issues. I'm trying to remove the space between a image and a label, and it does not work.
This is what I have:
[image]

And this is what I want:
[image]

I have problems with removing the space below he pictures and the same problem with the labels and the other div below them. In the same time I do not know how to position inline the headers from the footer.

This is my fiddle with my html and css: 
https://jsfiddle.net/cwd6qw3o/

```
 div img {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 30%;
        width: 23%;
    }

    div.subtitle {
        background-color: #333333;
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 0;
        text-align: left;
        width: 23%;
    }

    div.subcolor {
        background-color: #ba0927;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 5px;
        width: 23%;
    }

    div.footer {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
        width: 100%;
        height: 5%;
    }
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong :).
Thanks !

Comment: You have a `div:after` in the fiddle, which gets applied to each and every div on the page. If you remove that, it will go a long way towards solving your problem. Also, "Routebeschrijving" is misspelled. And I'm not sure what you mean by "position inline the headers from the footer".

Comment: I mean the Houman BVBA and Openingsuren is not on the same line, but if i add 2 lines in the first div which contains BVBA then are in the same line, and i don't want to add two more rows just to align the headers. Also if i remove div:after i lose the spacing between the images.

Comment: The problem in the footer also will vanish if you remove the `div:after` rule from the stylesheet.

Comment: If i remove div:after i lose my spacing between images.

Comment: Use padding for spacing. That's what padding is for.

Comment: Ok, now my fiddle is this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3bzhvude/) where to put padding? If i put in the div with the pictures is not helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not a good structure in your HTML,why not wrap your item in the same `li` such as

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="~/Content/cont1.png"/>
        <p>Bosch Car Service</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="~/Content/cont2.png"/>
        <p>Afspraak Proefrit</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="~/Content/cont3.png"/>
        <p>Afspraak onderhoud</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="~/Content/cont4.png"/>
        <p>Routebeschrijiving</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Or, use a `<picture>`. This is exactly what `<picture>` was designed for. By the way, you're using `<p>`, which will have a margin of its own, so you're not really solving the OP's problem. (As you can see in the OP's fiddle, he's not using a reset stylesheet.)

Comment: If i do this  lose that tiny little red line under the image, alose <picture> is not supported by safari.

Comment: Oh,you are right, `<picture>` is more exactly and powerful.and `<p>` dose need to reset its style.I am just too concerned of its structure. : )

Comment: I think using a specific tag to make a red line is not a good way too.In my structure you can give `li` a `border-bottom` property to make a red bottom line.

Comment: I tried with ul and li and the slide picture will not appear how i want to, do you know why?

Comment: I hope this can give you some inspiration [xjzr2yzf](https://jsfiddle.net/nutto/xjzr2yzf/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove spaces with the following CSS:

```
div {
    font-size: 0;
}

div.subtitle {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Live preview: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwd6qw3o/1/)

Additional styling is necessary.

Comment: If I do this, the Information from the footer dissapers. :)

Comment: Then you have to apply the font-size: 1rem; also to the div.information or div.footer, depending on your code.

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

```
div::after {
    content: "";
    width: 60%;
}


.image-div {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

div img {
    float: left;
    height: 30%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 23%;
}

div.subtitle {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 23%;
}

.sub-div {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
div.subcolor {
    background-color: #ba0927;
    float: left;
    height: 5px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 23%;
}

<body>
    <img src="~/Content/slide1.png" id="slide" />

    <div class="image-div">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"/>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="sub-div">
        <div class="subtitle">
            Bosch Car Service
        </div>
        <div class="subtitle">
            Afspraak Proefrit
        </div>
        <div class="subtitle">
            Afspraak onderhoud
        </div>
        <div class="subtitle">
            Routebeschrijiving
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="subcolor" id="sub1"></div>
        <div class="subcolor" id="sub2"></div>
        <div class="subcolor" id="sub3"></div>
        <div class="subcolor" id="sub4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="images">
            <img src="~/Content/fb.jpg"/>
            <img src="~/Content/contact.jpg"/>
            <img src="~/Content/route.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="information">
            <div class="contact">
                <h1>Houman BVBA</h1>
                <label>Boterstraat 6</label>
                <label>B-2811 Hombeek (Mechelen)</label>
                <label>Tel. 015 41 39 39</label>
                <label>Fax. 015/43 24 40</label>
            </div>
            <div class="schedule">
                <h1>Openingsuren</h1>
                <label>Maandag: 9u-12u|13u-18u</label>
                <label>Dinsdag: 9u-12u|13u-18u</label>
                <label>Woensdag: 9u-12u|13u-18u</label>
                <label>Donderdag: 9u-12u|13u-18u</label>
                <label>Vrijdag: 9u-12u|13u-18u</label>
                <label>Zaterdag: 9u-12u|13u-18u</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is between this and the OP's source?